# Routing to two WCF services through router

Tags: wcf, service, routes

I'm working in an application where a third-party has exposed two services one is a legacy service built on a different platform and another one is built on WCF. Based on the request from the client I've to redirect to either one of the service. I'm planning to create a WCF router can anyone share some good links for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4 you can use the RoutingService - this supports data dependent routing. I recorded a series of screencasts about it [here](http://www.rocksolidknowledge.com/ScreenCasts.mvc) and there is one specifically about data dependent routing [here](http://www.rocksolidknowledge.com/Screencasts.mvc/Watch?video=DataDependentRouting.wmv)

Comment: Nice video. I've a doubt with filters. In my case the client will send a parameter in the soap message so based on that I'll redirect to the particular service through filter but if they don't send any  parameter then I've to do a database query and based on that the particular service will be invoked. Can you plz tell me how i can achieve this in the router?

Comment: There is another video on using custom filters which sounds like what you'll need to do - you write the logic to decide whether the filter is a match. In fact there is yet another one on advanced custom filters that shows you how to take full control over a section of the routing table

Comment: Thanks Richard. You have done some nice videos, can't wait to watch all.

Comment: Outstanding videos Richard! It's so much clear to me how wcf routing works. Thank u very much!